# Is the "\t" the same as tapping the tab button on your keybaord?

Tags: java

The title says it all, is there any real reason that:

```
print("\t");
```

Can't do what

```
print("        ");
```

does?

Clarification: I am not asking if one is better than the other, I am asking if one can do anything that the other can not.

Comment: To answer the question in the title: yes.

Comment: One is the tabulator character, the others are just 8 spaces. They are different.

Comment: the tab key prints the tab character which is the `char` `'\t'`

Comment: That entirely depends on your editor.  Some editors take tabs and replace them with spaces to make source code more portable.  But if you can put a literal tab character in there, yes, they do the same thing.

Comment: try scanning many tubs in and printing them out as HEX.

Comment: Also, depending on the settings, the tab may return/reserve the specified number of spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tab character is not the same as inserting spaces and when you hit tab on your keyboard, your IDE appears to have entered multiple spaces for you.

Example:

```
System.out.println("A\tB");
System.out.println("123\t456");
```

Outputs:

```
A   B
123 456
```

The tab character has moved the cursor to the next tab stop, which has helped align these columns.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is the same. \t is the escape sequence for the tab space.

```
System.out.println("Hello\tWorld");
```

It will provide:

```
Hello   World
```